# Errors lazy loading failed for package 'devtools'

Tags: r

im trying to install  DEVTOOLS but i keep getting the error showing . can any one assist please. The 2 errors as showing below

```
error 1:package usethis was built under R version 4.0.5 
Error in loadNamespace
error 2:ERROR: lazy loading failed for package devtools
```

Here is my code

```
install.packages("blockmodeling", dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("aslez/concoR")
```

```
install.packages("blockmodeling", dependencies = TRUE)
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/eslam/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/blockmodeling_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 410411 bytes (400 KB)
downloaded 400 KB

package ‘blockmodeling’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\eslam\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6nB24u\downloaded_packages
> install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/eslam/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘pkgload’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
pkgload   1.2.0  1.2.1              TRUE
devtools  2.3.2  2.4.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/pkgload_1.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 151933 bytes (148 KB)
downloaded 148 KB

package ‘pkgload’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\eslam\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6nB24u\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘devtools’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 369987 bytes (361 KB)
downloaded 361 KB

* installing *source* package 'devtools' ...
** package 'devtools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning message:
package 'usethis' was built under R version 4.0.5 
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'pkgload' 1.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.2.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted

> ERROR

: lazy loading failed for package 'devtools'
* removing 'C:/Users/eslam/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/devtools'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\eslam\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6nB24u\downloaded_packages’
> library(devtools)
Error in library(devtools) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
> devtools::install_github("aslez/concoR")
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
```

Comment: Restart RStudio and try installing your package by source.

Comment: hello there, i dont that same errors

Comment: Did you try installing the package by source? First remove your current installation using `remove.packages("devtools")`, then restart RStudio and use `install.packages("devtools", type = "source")`. Thereafter, load it using `library()`. Namespaces issues can arise from cluttered R sessions, so it's advisable to restart again.

Comment: What is your version of R?

Comment: Also, although its optional, I recommend installing Rtools.

Comment: Thank you, @user11422223, I had a similar problem, and after doing what you recommended, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks everyone for the support.

I figured it out . I had to run

```
install.packages( "devtools", type="win.binary" )
```

Comment: Thank you! I think you are missing a quotation. 

`install.packages("devtools", type="win.binary")`